# Can't make this "If" clause work

Tags: function-construction, conditional

I am writing a code that creates a population with a probability to die for each citizen. They all start with some age, and after each application of the function, it either kills a person or adds +1 day (or year or month or whatever) to their life counter. It looks as follows:

```
P = {Subscript[a, #], RandomReal[{0.8, 0.99999999999}], 20} & /@ Range[5];
```

creates

```
{{a_1, 0.9931, 20}, {a_2, 0.985863, 20}, {a_3, 0.93499, 20}, {a_4, 0.83093, 20}, {a_5, 0.844538, 20}}
```

each citizen has a name, a probability to die, and the age. The function that kills a person or lets them live is

```
mor[x_] := If[Length[x] <= 1, x, If[RandomReal[] >= x[[2]], "M", x]]
```

which when applied to P gives it and "M" if they die or leaves them the same otherwise, as follows

```
mor[#] & /@ P

{{a_1, 0.9931, 20}, {a_2, 0.985863, 20}, {a_3, 0.93499, 20}, M, M}
```

As you can see, the age (20) counter of the citizens did not change. I want it to change and add +1 every time the function "mor" is applied but I don't know how to. For example, it should look like this after some steps:

```
{{a_1, 0.9931, 21}, {a_2, 0.985863, 21}, {a_3, 0.93499, 21}, M, M}
{{a_1, 0.9931, 22}, {a_2, 0.985863, 22}, {a_3, 0.93499, 22}, M, M}
{M, {a_2, 0.985863, 23}, {a_3, 0.93499, 23}, M, M}
```

etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `If[..]` never changes the third entry in `x`. Maybe `MapAt[ #+1&, x, 3]` instead of the last `x` in `mor[]`?

Comment: maybe `ClearAll[mor];
mor[x_] :=  If[Length[x] <= 1, x, If[RandomReal[] >= x[[2]], "M", {0, 0, 1} + x]]
SeedRandom[1];
NestList[Map[mor], P, 5]`?

Comment: Ok, both ideas work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
P = {Subscript[a, #], RandomReal[{0.8, 0.99999999999}], 20} & /@  Range[5];

ClearAll[mor1]
mor1[x_] := If[x === "M", "M", If[RandomReal[] >= x[[2]], "M", {0, 0, 1} + x]]

SeedRandom[11111]
NestList[Map[mor1], P, 10] // Column
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[11111]
Most @ FixedPointList[Map[mor1], P] // Column
```

[image]

Alterantively,

```
ClearAll[mor2]
mor2["M"] = "M";
mor2[x_List] := If[RandomReal[] >= x[[2]], "M", {0, 0, 1} + x]

SeedRandom[11111]
NestList[Map[mor2], P, 10] // Column
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[11111]
Most @ FixedPointList[Map[mor2], P] // Column
```

[image]